# How to get Chromium working on Pi-3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, chromium

I follow the steps below

```
> wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main dev" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser rpi-youtube -y
```

Now have a "Chromium Web Browser" in the Internet category drop down but clicking on it causes the "working" icon to spin for a few seconds and then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Jessie is supposed to have chromium in it's default package list. Try purging your current chromium install, and then install like you would any other package (sudo apt-get install chromium blabla)

If it still is not working, try running chromium-browser from a terminal, you should get an error message that better descirbed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me this morning:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chromium-ppa.list
```

Contents of new file:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu vivid main

#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu vivid main

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DB69B232436DAC4B50BDC59E4E1B983C5B393194
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```